# como criar um bloco de exibir codigo c++/java em HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

tenho um codigo JAVA, gostaria de publica-lo num site. Como faço isso? Estou usando folhas de estio css mas elas "estragam os espaços" entre as chaves e nã mostram o código JAVA em high light, como corrijo este problema de "comer os espaços" e o problema de adicionar sintax Hylight nos Blocos de código JAVA? isso na exibição em um site.

Comment: Está usando alguma lib pra fazer esse highlight? Ou jogando o código java entre as tags html e formatando com css nativo?

Comment: Veja sobre o [Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), talvez lhe seja útil.

Comment: estou  jogando o código java entre as tags html e formatando com css nativo, sou iniciante...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo usar o [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/). Ele funciona em mais de 174 linguagens e 77 estilos.

Você pode baixa-lo e para usar só adicionar no HEAD da página

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/default.css">
<script src="/path/to/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Depois só colocaro código para dar highlight dentro das tags assim:

```
<pre><code class="html">...</code></pre>
```

Ele detecta automático também sem precisar marcar a linguagem.